# dse cassandra start up error - org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager

Tags: hadoop, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.1, datastax-startup

I am trying to start DSE Search the first time after "tar xvf dse-4.7.8-bin.tar.gz". Below is the error:

```
[spark@osboxes dse-4.7.8]$ bin/dse cassandra -s
Tomcat: Logging to /home/spark/tomcat
[spark@osboxes dse-4.7.8]$ INFO  21:59:57  Loading DSE module
INFO  21:59:57  Loading settings from file:/usr/mware/dse-4.7.8/resources/dse/conf/dse.yaml
INFO  21:59:58  Load of settings is done.
INFO  21:59:58  CQL slow log is not enabled
INFO  21:59:58  CQL system info tables are not enabled
INFO  21:59:58  Resource level latency tracking is not enabled
INFO  21:59:58  Database summary stats are not enabled
INFO  21:59:58  Cluster summary stats are not enabled
INFO  21:59:58  Histogram data tables are not enabled
INFO  21:59:58  User level latency tracking is not enabled
INFO  21:59:58  Spark cluster info tables are not enabled
INFO  21:59:58  Loading settings from file:/usr/mware/dse-4.7.8/resources/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml
INFO  21:59:58  Node configuration:[authenticator=AllowAllAuthenticator; authorizer=AllowAllAuthorizer; auto_snapshot=true; batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb=64; batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb=1024; cas_contention_timeout_in_ms=1000; client_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; cluster_name=Test Cluster; column_index_size_in_kb=64; commit_failure_policy=stop; commitlog_directory=/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog; commitlog_segment_size_in_mb=32; commitlog_sync=periodic; commitlog_sync_period_in_ms=10000; compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb=100; compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec=16; concurrent_counter_writes=32; concurrent_reads=32; concurrent_writes=32; counter_cache_save_period=7200; counter_cache_size_in_mb=null; counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; cross_node_timeout=false; data_file_directories=[/var/lib/cassandra/data]; disk_failure_policy=stop; dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold=0.1; dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms=600000; dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms=100; endpoint_snitch=com.datastax.bdp.snitch.DseSimpleSnitch; hinted_handoff_enabled=true; hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb=1024; incremental_backups=false; index_summary_capacity_in_mb=null; index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes=60; inter_dc_tcp_nodelay=false; internode_compression=dc; key_cache_save_period=14400; key_cache_size_in_mb=null; listen_address=localhost; max_hint_window_in_ms=10800000; max_hints_delivery_threads=2; memtable_allocation_type=heap_buffers; native_transport_port=9042; partitioner=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner; permissions_validity_in_ms=2000; range_request_timeout_in_ms=10000; read_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; request_scheduler=org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler; request_timeout_in_ms=10000; row_cache_save_period=0; row_cache_size_in_mb=0; rpc_address=localhost; rpc_keepalive=true; rpc_port=9160; rpc_server_type=sync; saved_caches_directory=/var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches; seed_provider=[{class_name=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider, parameters=[{seeds=127.0.0.1}]}]; server_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; snapshot_before_compaction=false; ssl_storage_port=7001; sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb=50; start_native_transport=true; start_rpc=true; storage_port=7000; thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb=15; tombstone_failure_threshold=100000; tombstone_warn_threshold=1000; trickle_fsync=false; trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb=10240; truncate_request_timeout_in_ms=60000; write_request_timeout_in_ms=2000]
INFO  21:59:58  DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
INFO  21:59:58  Global memtable on-heap threshold is enabled at 545MB
INFO  21:59:58  Global memtable off-heap threshold is enabled at 545MB
INFO  21:59:58  Detected search service is enabled, setting my workload to Search
INFO  21:59:58  Detected search service is enabled, setting my DC to Solr
INFO  21:59:58  Initialized DseDelegateSnitch with workload Search, delegating to com.datastax.bdp.snitch.DseSimpleSnitch
INFO  21:59:58  Loading settings from file:/usr/mware/dse-4.7.8/resources/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml
INFO  21:59:58  Node configuration:[authenticator=AllowAllAuthenticator; authorizer=AllowAllAuthorizer; auto_snapshot=true; batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb=64; batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb=1024; cas_contention_timeout_in_ms=1000; client_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; cluster_name=Test Cluster; column_index_size_in_kb=64; commit_failure_policy=stop; commitlog_directory=/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog; commitlog_segment_size_in_mb=32; commitlog_sync=periodic; commitlog_sync_period_in_ms=10000; compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb=100; compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec=16; concurrent_counter_writes=32; concurrent_reads=32; concurrent_writes=32; counter_cache_save_period=7200; counter_cache_size_in_mb=null; counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; cross_node_timeout=false; data_file_directories=[/var/lib/cassandra/data]; disk_failure_policy=stop; dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold=0.1; dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms=600000; dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms=100; endpoint_snitch=com.datastax.bdp.snitch.DseSimpleSnitch; hinted_handoff_enabled=true; hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb=1024; incremental_backups=false; index_summary_capacity_in_mb=null; index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes=60; inter_dc_tcp_nodelay=false; internode_compression=dc; key_cache_save_period=14400; key_cache_size_in_mb=null; listen_address=localhost; max_hint_window_in_ms=10800000; max_hints_delivery_threads=2; memtable_allocation_type=heap_buffers; native_transport_port=9042; partitioner=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner; permissions_validity_in_ms=2000; range_request_timeout_in_ms=10000; read_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; request_scheduler=org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler; request_timeout_in_ms=10000; row_cache_save_period=0; row_cache_size_in_mb=0; rpc_address=localhost; rpc_keepalive=true; rpc_port=9160; rpc_server_type=sync; saved_caches_directory=/var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches; seed_provider=[{class_name=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider, parameters=[{seeds=127.0.0.1}]}]; server_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; snapshot_before_compaction=false; ssl_storage_port=7001; sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb=50; start_native_transport=true; start_rpc=true; storage_port=7000; thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb=15; tombstone_failure_threshold=100000; tombstone_warn_threshold=1000; trickle_fsync=false; trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb=10240; truncate_request_timeout_in_ms=60000; write_request_timeout_in_ms=2000]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/security/token/delegation/AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at com.datastax.bdp.DseCoreModule.bindSecretManager(DseCoreModule.java:74)
        at com.datastax.bdp.DseCoreModule.configure(DseCoreModule.java:60)
        at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:59)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)
        at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.install(AbstractModule.java:118)
        at com.datastax.bdp.server.AbstractDseModule.configure(AbstractDseModule.java:28)
        at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.configure(DseModule.java:35)
        at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:59)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:101)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:133)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:103)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
        at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.main(DseModule.java:71)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 28 more
```

There has been no change in any configuration. I have only set "HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/mware/dse-4.7.8/resources/hadoop/conf " in the .bashrc file (and of course I ran . ~/.bashrc afterwards). Am I missing something here? "bin/dse cassandra" is also having the same error. OS is CentOS 7.2.1511 64 bit.

Comment: Can you confirm that the following file exists /usr/mware/dse-4.7.8/resources/hadoop/lib/hadoop-core-1.0.4.15.jar

Comment: Yes. the file is there.
  `ls -ltr /usr/mware/dse-4.7.8/resources/hadoop/lib/hadoop-core*`
`  `
`-rw-rw-r-- 1 spark spark 3968310 Apr  5 02:50 /usr/mware/dse-4.7.8/resources/hadoop/lib/hadoop-core-1.0.4.15.jar`

Comment: Thanks everybody. **I got the reason why I was encountering the issue while starting up.** I was having a separate installation of Apache Hadoop at other location and it's environment information was set in .bashrc file. Before running dse cassandra, I was commenting out those variables in the file and subsequently, executing .bashrc, but was missing the point that those variable would still be there unless I do relogin. My bad.